# How to control the thickness of lines in the Hierarchical Edge Bundling chart?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Is it possible to increase/decrease the thickness of lines in the [Hierarchical Edge Bundling](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) chart?

For example, in the input data there is a `size` defined, but I don't see its effect in the chart. Is it possible to make more "fat" lines when the size is bigger?

I added this line of code:

```
.attr('stroke-width', function(d) { return d.size; })
```

...in order to define `stroke-width` based on the field `size` from the input data file `readme-flare-imports.json`. However, it doesn't have any effect.

```
 link = link
      .data(bundle(links))
      .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('stroke-width', function(d) { return d.size; })
      .attr("d", line);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `datum` in your `attr` function is an array of all the links of that particular node.

So, to get the `size` value of the source only, it should be:

```
.attr("stroke-width", function(d){
    return d[0].size;
})
```

As the numeric values of the `size` property are huge, I'm using a scale, in which the width goes from 1 to 10:

```
var sizeScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(classes, function(d){ return d.size})])
    .range([1, 10]);  

link.attr("stroke-width", function(d){
    return sizeScale(d[0].size)
})
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cad2m2ue/

Comment: Do you have any recommendation how to make this kind of chart more informative? Maybe color gradient would be better to define the thickness instead ofonly using the width? Or maybe the stroe width should be on the logarithmic scale?

Comment: To change colors (besides thinckness) depending on the value of `size`, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work: `var colors = ["#c7e9b4","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8"];

var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain(0, d3.max(classes, function(d){ return d.size})])
  .range(colors);

link.attr("stroke", function(d){
    return colorScale(d[0].size)
});`

Comment: @Dinosaurius, for your `colorScale`, you probably want to use `d3.scale.quantile` and `d3.extent`.  Also, you need to set the stroke `style` (not attr), since you css already defines a stroke style - [style is more specific then attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).  See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cad2m2ue/1/)